# How to get compass direction

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

I want to show the direction on the screen that phone is facing.  For example:

```
   0
   |- []
   |_
  South --- North
```

In the above diagram the phone would display "North".  Since the user (the stick with 0 for his head) is holding out the phone (the [] in the diagram) pointing north.

I found [this example](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/development/samples/Compass/src/com/example/android/compass/CompassActivity.java).  I understand what it's doing except it seems to calculate yaw, pitch, roll, and inclination.  What are those and how would I use them to simply find which way the phone is pointing?

Also this [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float[],%20float[])) mentions X, Y, and Z axises but I don't see anywhere that says how those axises correspond to the phone?  Is Z going from the bottom of the phone to the top?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaw_angle

Comment: I also noticed the GeomagneticField class has getX and getY methods? Can I use that instead?  It doesn't have any kind of sensorChanged altert though.  Would I have to make my own loop to poll it?

Comment: This article might be useful to you.  You need to be caerful about assumptions about screen orientation when displaying directions on teh screen. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html

Answer (score 5):

[this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) is how the axis (axiy?) look like.

I couldn't find a link to the cheat sheet I use, but it looked sort of like [this](http://novoda.com/2009/05/02/motion-sensors-and-orientation-in-android/).

In summary, you want to register to listen for Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION, from the incoming array of values get, value[0] and that should show you your angle (from North I believe).

some [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Compass.html) from *android.com

Comment: Thanks.  What happens if the phone is in landscape mode?

Comment: according to this post, http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=11b73cc231c318af&hl=en its basically a hardware compass, so it should behave normally in landscape mode

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` has been deprecated, in favour of `SensorManager.getOrientation()`.